# Unloading my plugin from another process

Tags: cocoa, plugins, dock, nsbundle

I'm toying with adding an [`NSDockTilePlugIn`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSDockTilePlugIn_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to my application, but I've come across some strange behavior -- understandable behavior, but I'd like to see if there is a way around it.

When I run my app from the dmg or keep the (dmg version of the) app in the Dock, the Dock loads my .docktileplugin bundle.
When the application quits, the plugin receives a `setDockTile:` message with a `nil` `NSDockTile *` (as per the documentation).  However, the plugin keeps running, and I cannot eject (unmount, detach) the dmg unless I kill the Dock (I suppose logging out would work too).

I've tried sending a Notification through the `NSDistributedNotificaitonCenter` (from a non-dmg version of the app) to tell it to unload, but the Console tells me that now I have two of the same docktileplugin loaded, and it is undefined which one will execute.
And even though [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:...] unload] returns `YES`, I still cannot eject the dmg.